# Upload Excel Workbook on shared drive

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a master workbook which gathers the data from other Excel workbooks. Below is the path where my other workbooks are placed (from which data need to be gathered) and my master workbook is on desktop. Below is the code I am using.

```
' Change this to the path\folder location of the files.
MyPath = "C:\P&G\"

' Add a slash at the end of path if needed.
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    MyPath = MyPath & "\"
End If

' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
If FilesInPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Fill in the myFiles array with the list of Excel files in
' the search folder.
FNum = 0
Do While FilesInPath <> ""
    FNum = FNum + 1
    ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
    MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
    FilesInPath = Dir()
Loop
```

When I am uploading this file on shared drive, I am giving my path as follows:

`"\\151.208.196.138\ATS shared drive\F&HC\PSG OPS\New DDS Sheet"`

But this is giving error. can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

The UNC (*Universal Naming Convention*) is basically the full file path location.  It takes the format:

```
\\Server\Share\filepath
```

Notice the `"\\"`?

In your case, it will be

```
"\\151.208.196.138\ATS shared drive\F&HC\PSG OPS\New DDS Sheet"
```

Comment: Still giving error. If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
there is a bug in FilesInPath. :(

Comment: change `Dir(MyPath & ".xl")` to `Dir(MyPath & ".xl*")`

Comment: debug and check what does MyPath have?

Comment: On my PC my shared drive is displayed like this ("\\151.208.196.138\ats) (Z:). So if I write my code like this 
"Z:\F&HC\PSG OPS\New DDS Sheet\".
it works. But if some other person opens the shared drive this Z folder will be let's say Y: on his PC. So it will not work on his PC. There's a problem with my 151.208.196.138 code line. There must be a way or a function to display such numerical values that I am missing in my code.

Comment: Try this `"\\151.208.196.138\F&HC\PSG OPS\New DDS Sheet"`

Comment: No again giving error 52. Actually i am a bit new at VBA. How to debug and check what does MyPath have?

Comment: If you type `\\151.208.196.138\ATS shared drive\F&HC\PSG OPS\New DDS Sheet` in the windows explorer, does it take you to the correct folder?

Comment: no items found, when I tried to search it in windows explorer

Comment: forget the items. Does it take you to the correct folder? If not then that means your path is incorrect